# MySQL SELECT in a UNION statement is not able to refer to the parent table

Tags: mysql, select, union, sugarcrm

I'm trying to execute the following MySQL SELECT statement, to get the date of the last activity done against a every parent opportunity id.

The list of activities will be retrieved from 4 tables: calls, meetings, tasks, emails.

I'm getting a syntax error when I add the the condition "XXXXX.parent_id = opportunities.id" (in the inner 4 sub-SELECTS).

If I delete "XXXXX.parent_id = opportunities.id", the statements gets executed (but, of course, results are irrelevant to what I want).

Here is the code I'm tried:

```
SELECT
opportunities.id,
opportunities.name,
(
    SELECT MAX(`last_activity_date`) FROM
        (
        SELECT c.date_end AS `last_activity_date`     
        FROM calls AS c     
        WHERE c.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND c.parent_id = opportunities.id      
        AND c.status IN ('Held')      
        AND c.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT m.date_end     
        FROM meetings AS m     
        WHERE m.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND m.parent_id = opportunities.id      
        AND m.status IN ('Held')      
        AND m.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT t.date_due     
        FROM tasks AS t     
        WHERE t.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND t.parent_id = opportunities.id      
        AND t.status IN ('Completed')      
        AND t.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT e.date_sent     
        FROM emails AS e     
        WHERE e.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND e.parent_id = opportunities.id      
        AND e.status IN ('sent', 'archived')      
        AND e.deleted = '0'    
    ) AS `activities`  
) AS "opportunities_activities"     

FROM opportunities   
WHERE opportunities.deleted = '0'     
ORDER BY opportunities.id ASC
```

Comment: where is your condition XXXXX.parent_id = opportunities.id

Comment: Can you place your tables with some example data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use outer query fields inside the inner nested query as each inner query must be independent of any outer query.

Try query below for desired result.

```
SELECT
opportunities.id,
opportunities.name,
(
    SELECT MAX(`last_activity_date`) FROM
        (
        SELECT c.date_end AS `last_activity_date`     
        FROM calls AS c     
        join opportunities o on c.parent_id = o.id
        WHERE c.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND c.status IN ('Held')      
        AND c.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT m.date_end     
        FROM meetings AS m     
        join opportunities o on m.parent_id = o.id
        WHERE m.parent_type = 'Opportunities'           
        AND m.status IN ('Held')      
        AND m.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT t.date_due     
        FROM tasks AS t 
        join opportunities o on t.parent_id = o.id    
        WHERE t.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND t.status IN ('Completed')      
        AND t.deleted = '0'     

        UNION

        SELECT e.date_sent     
        FROM emails AS e  
        join opportunities o on e.parent_id = o.id
        WHERE e.parent_type = 'Opportunities'      
        AND e.status IN ('sent', 'archived')      
        AND e.deleted = '0'    
    ) AS `activities`  
) AS "opportunities_activities"     

FROM opportunities   
WHERE opportunities.deleted = '0'     
ORDER BY opportunities.id ASC
```